# .net ora-06502 character string buffer too small

Tags: .net, vb.net, oracle, oracle11g

When I tried to execute a query from .net code (odac 11g) I obtain this message:

> ora-06502 character string buffer too small

This is the query, it's very simple:

```
SELECT t.ID_VAL, t.DS_VAL || '(' || t.ID_VAL || ')' AS DS_VAL 
FROM T_VALS t 
ORDER BY t.DS_VAL
```

And this is the table's spec

```
ID_VAL  VARCHAR2(3), DS_VAL VARCHAR2(50)
```

I tried to increase the size of `ID_VAL` column, but I obtain always the same error.

Comment: whats the .net code look like?

Comment: A guess - perhaps the `t.DS_VAL || etc AS DS_VAL` has confused things by using `DS_VAL` as the result column. Try using another name for the column alias, for example `t.DS_VAL || '(' || t.ID_VAL || ')' AS DS_Formatted_Val`. If that doesn't work out, try specifying the size of the result: `SELECT ... CAST(t.DS_VAL || '(' || t.ID_VAL || ')' AS VARCHAR2(55)) AS ...`.